# VBA End Private Sub if First Sub Routine is exited

Tags: vba, exit, private-pub

I want the entire Private Sub to Exit if the Copier routine is exited. So the DoDays routines is never called.

```
Sub Copier()
Dim x As String
Dim z As Integer
x = InputBox("Enter Number of Days in Month")
If x = "" Then
     MsgBox "User Pressed Cancel!" & vbCrLf & _
            "or did not enter a value!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
            "Inputbox Result:"
     z = 10
     Exit Sub
ElseIf CInt(x) = 0 Then
     MsgBox "User Pressed Cancel!" & vbCrLf & _
            "or did not enter a value!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
            "Inputbox Result:"
     z = 10
     Exit Sub
Else: End If
y = CInt(x) - 1
For numtimes = 1 To y
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Next

DoDays

End Sub



Private Sub COPY_NUMBER_Click()
COPY_NUMBER.BackColor = 12713921
Copier
' DoDays
COPY_NUMBER.BackColor = 12500670
COPY_NUMBER.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

The call to the DoDays in the Copier sub doesn't seem to work because I literally need to exit the Private Sub so the button remains enabled.

Comment: Create a global variable and update it at the end of your Copier method then check it before DoDays is called....

Comment: that sounds easy enough, let me try shortly thanks.

Comment: Or call `DoDays` (when required) from within `Copier` instead of from within `COPY_NUMBER_Click`.  (But that will still leave `COPY_NUMBER.BackColor = 12500670` `COPY_NUMBER.Enabled = True` being executed within `COPY_NUMBER_Click`, so maybe that isn't a good idea, or maybe it is a better idea than exiting before those statements.)

Comment: Or switch `copier` to a boolean function and set it equal to true just before the `End Function`. Then switch your call to `If Not Copier Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: ^ basically *anything* but a global variable ;-)

Comment: Seems like second answers works better.  What did I do wrong in the first? See image above.

Comment: Oh, please don't do that. Paste your actual code into the post, with 4 leading spaces for every line (like you did with that code block at the top). Nobody wants to work off screenshots.

Comment: What you did wrong is not making it a global variable. You declared `z` within `Copier` so its scope is limited to that one procedure.

Comment: Move your `COPY_NUMBER.BackColor = 12500670` `COPY_NUMBER.Enabled = False` statements after where `DoDays` now is.  (Or, better still, just move your `Copier` code into `COPY_NUMBER_Click`.)

Comment: So I want them to be able to click the button again to enter the copier input again so last option is not an option.

Comment: Global variable works.  Can you post as answer so I can accept.

Comment: @ChristopherD. how do I set the copier function to a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

I would merge the `Copier` procedure into the `COPY_NUMBER_Click` event procedure:

```
Private Sub COPY_NUMBER_Click()
    COPY_NUMBER.BackColor = 12713921

    Dim x As String
    x = InputBox("Enter Number of Days in Month")
    If x = "" Then
         MsgBox "User Pressed Cancel!" & vbCrLf & _
                "or did not enter a value!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
                "Inputbox Result:"
         Exit Sub
    ElseIf CInt(x) = 0 Then
         MsgBox "User Pressed Cancel!" & vbCrLf & _
                "or did not enter a value!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
                "Inputbox Result:"
         Exit Sub
    End If
    y = CInt(x) - 1
    For numtimes = 1 To y
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
                     After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Next

    DoDays

    COPY_NUMBER.BackColor = 12500670
    COPY_NUMBER.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: that would probably work also,  i will test that later

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable and update it at the end of your Copier method then check it before DoDays is called

```
Private bRunDoDays As Boolean
Sub Copier()
'set to false
bRunDoDays = False
Dim x As String
Dim z As Integer
x = InputBox("Enter Number of Days in Month")
If x = "" Then
     MsgBox "User Pressed Cancel!" & vbCrLf & _
            "or did not enter a value!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
            "Inputbox Result:"
     z = 10
     Exit Sub
ElseIf CInt(x) = 0 Then
     MsgBox "User Pressed Cancel!" & vbCrLf & _
            "or did not enter a value!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, _
            "Inputbox Result:"
     z = 10
     Exit Sub
Else: End If
y = CInt(x) - 1
For numtimes = 1 To y
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
after:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Next
'set to true
bRunDoDays = True

End Sub



Private Sub COPY_NUMBER_Click()
COPY_NUMBER.BackColor = 12713921
Copier
If bRunDoDays = False Then Exit Sub
DoDays
COPY_NUMBER.BackColor = 12500670
COPY_NUMBER.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `Copier` to a Boolean Function and edit the call to test whether it executed successfully.

Your call would look like:

```
If Not Copier Then Exit Sub
```

Your `Copier` Function would look like:

```
Public Function Copier() As Boolean   
  'Does Stuff
  Copier = True
End Function
```

Make sure you have `Option Explicit` enabled. It should have thrown a compile error on the `If z = 10 Then Exit Sub` since it is out of scope.